# Resource locker in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, synchronization, qt

The idea is to lock resources in C# or Java using Qt:

```
lock(obj){/*process with locked obj*/}`
```

Now I see the problem with deleting `obj` under `lock()`.

**resourcelocker.h**

```
#ifndef RESOURCELOCKER_H
#define RESOURCELOCKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QHash>
#include <QSemaphore>

class ResourceLocker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    friend class ResourceWatcher;
    explicit ResourceLocker(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~ResourceLocker();

    bool lock();

private:
    static QHash<QObject*,QSemaphore*> resources;
    QSemaphore * sem;
    QObject * expectedParent;
    bool doubleLock;

signals:

public slots:

};

#define _LOCK(object) for (ResourceLocker locker((object)); locker.lock(); )

#endif // RESOURCELOCKER_H
```

**resourcelocker.cpp**

```
#include "resourcelocker.h"
#include <QMutex>
#include <QMutexLocker>
#include <QSemaphore>
#include <QDebug>

QHash<QObject* ,QSemaphore*> ResourceLocker::resources;

class ResourceWatcher: public QObject
{
public:
    explicit ResourceWatcher(QObject * parent):
        QObject(parent)
    {
        //qDebug()<<"creating watcher";
    }

    ~ResourceWatcher()
    {
        QSemaphore * sem = ResourceLocker::resources.value(parent(),NULL);
        if (sem->available()>0)
        {
            //unlocked
            ResourceLocker::resources.remove(parent());
            delete sem;
        }
        else
        {
            //locked
            ResourceLocker::resources.remove(parent());
        }
        //qDebug()<<"removing sem";

    }
};

ResourceLocker::ResourceLocker(QObject *parent) :QObject(),expectedParent(parent),doubleLock(false)
{
}

bool ResourceLocker::lock()
{
    static QMutex internalMutex;
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&internalMutex);

        if (doubleLock)
            return false;
        doubleLock = true;
        //qDebug()<<&expectedParent;

        sem = resources.value(expectedParent,NULL);
        if (sem == NULL)
        {
            //qDebug()<<"Crearting sem";
            sem = new QSemaphore(1);
            resources.insert(expectedParent,sem);
            new ResourceWatcher(expectedParent);
        }
    }
    //qDebug()<<"acquiring";
   sem->acquire();
   return true;
}

ResourceLocker::~ResourceLocker()
{
    QMutex internalMutex;
    QMutexLocker locker(&internalMutex);
    //qDebug()<<"releasing";
    sem->release();
    if (!resources.values().contains(sem))
        delete sem;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
_LOCK(smth)
    {
        //prcoess with smth locked

    }
```

Comment: C++ is not Java or C#. Stop trying to apply concepts from other languages (in the other languages concept), it will just make learning to do things correctly harder. Learn how they are done in C++.

Comment: PS> _LOCK() is a reserved identifier.

Comment: Ok, I posted it here in hope that someone can show me real issues, connected with this code. Could you be more specific? Also, what alternative do you know to this in c++. I mean the way to synchronize access to some object with only knowing pointer to an object

Comment: The real issue here is not in the code but in the attempt to apply concepts that don't fit. As far as I am concerned there is no point in further analysis. Others may be able/willing to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There reason languages like Java has that feature is because they don't have RAII like C++ does.

I don't quite see how that is better than simply:

```
// Note: Braces for scope. "mutex" could optionally be declared static, or as a class member.
{ 
    QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);

    /* code */
}
```

Comment: A use case for my locker is when you have a resource (like file) and you access it in many places. If you just use mutex, you destroy encapsulation (you really need a pair of objects: real object and mutex to operate with real object) and  get missconcept (lock of mutex instead of resource realy)

Comment: If you access it in many places I would call it bad design, you are already breaking encapsulation. But lets say that's the case anyways, wouldn't it be easier and faster to simply create a LockableObject wrapper around the "resource"?

Comment: I agree, that creating a wrapper is a solution of the problem and that it would be faster, still my code is more universal solution (written once, can be used later without writing additional code)